# Django models: getting users from object

Tags: python, django, django-models

I just started with Django, I love it! It still is quite challenging however. I have a model Shift that has users assigned to it with the model Assign. I want to get all the users that are assigned to a certain shift, but I can only get the Assign objects. Do you guys know how I should change my query?

The problem above gives me these 2 models:

```
class Shift(models.Model):
    shift_location = models.CharField(max_length=200)

    def get_shift_users(self):
        Assign.objects.filter(shift=self)


class Assign(models.Model):
    shift = models.ForeignKey(Shift, unique=False)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, unique=False)
```

How do I return all users with the method get_shift_users, instead of all Assign objects? I thought that

```
Assign.objects.filter(shift=self).user
```

Would work...

Comment: Did you try starting with `User`?

Comment: Yes, that gives AttributeError: 'QuerySet' object has no attribute 'User'

Comment: I did say "start", didn't I?

Comment: `return Assign.objects.filter(shift=self)` ?

Comment: It might be a good idea to use a [many-to-many relationship](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/db/examples/many_to_many/) from `Shift` to `User`. It gives you a whole lot for free, e.g. you can do `shift.users.add(request.user)` to assign a shift to the current user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Starting from `User`

```
def get_shift_users(self):
   return User.objects.filter(assign_set__shift=self)
```

Comment: Thanks! That makes sense I guess. assign_set should be al Assign objects?

Comment: @user3361028 yep u right, is the backwards relationship attribute.